# vscode is showing compilation error on using lombok

Tags: maven, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, lombok

I am working on a spring boot project and added the maven dependency for lombok and also installed the ** Lombok Annotations Support for VS Code ** .I am using the latest version  of lombok and dependecy looks like this :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
     <version>1.18.28</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`
```

although my code is running without error and also vscode intellisense for lombok is working fine, It's showing unused warning and can't recognise the getter or constructors.
[image]

I tried to clean workspace and also cleaned the cache of vscode but still this problem persists. I am using vscode version

```
1.80.1
74f6148eb9ea00507ec113ec51c489d6ffb4b771
x64
```

in ubuntu 22.04. How can I fix this issue?